# jQuery(function ($) does not work after partial update in updatepanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
    jQuery(function ($) {
        //phone numbers
        alert("test");
        var txtInvestContactPhone = $("#<%=txtInvestContactPhone.ClientID%>");
        $(txtInvestContactPhone).mask("(999) 999-9999");


    });

</script>
```

i tried adding the pagerequestmanager to the content of the page, but i think i'm doing it wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add("jQuery(function ($)");
    </script>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

i've also tried to registerStartUp Script in my page_load event like so:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "jQuery(function ($);", true);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
```

but this just breaks my accordion causing the panels to all be unclickable.

i think i'm on the right path here, just need some help with syntax.

Comment: `jQuery(function ($);` isn't a function that can be called, that's like... half a function. Put your init code in it's own function definition, then call it from your DOM ready handler, and from your startup script.

Comment: thank you! please answer and i'll mark as correct! i knew i was close :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery(function ($);` isn't a function that can be called, that's like... half a function.

Put your init code in it's own function definition, then call it from your DOM ready handler, and from your startup script.

```
function init() {
    //phone numbers
    alert("test");
    var txtInvestContactPhone = jQuery("#<%=txtInvestContactPhone.ClientID%>");
    jQuery(txtInvestContactPhone).mask("(999) 999-9999");
});

jQuery(function () { init(); });
```

...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "init();", true);
```